# Is it odd to overestimate the danger of peak human characters or characters without powers?

Tags: fiction, fantasy, science-fiction, world-building, magic-system

**What does peak human mean in my world?**

There are two types of peak humans in my world: physical types and mental types. Physical types are the top tier in skills that involve hand-to-hand combat or martial arts. This includes the human body too. When it comes to strength, speed, agility, stamina, endurance, etc., a physical peak human can be the best martial artist on the planet.

Mental peak humans are at the top tier in skills that require intelligence, like hacking, science, etc. Certain skillsets can overlap between both types. For example, reaction time can be both mental and physical. Reaction time would of course translate to gun skills too. A mental peak human can be the smartest person on the planet.

There are also polymath peak humans, meaning they can master multiple skillsets at once. This means poly peak humans can be both mental and physical too. But poly peak humans can't know everything.

This brings me to Posthumans. Posthumans are the mutants of my world. Posthumans coexist with peak humans in the same world. Posthumans can have the same skill-based abilities as peak humans.

The only difference is that peak humans are still regular people in my world. It would take a peak human years or even decades to learn skills similar to a regular person, while it would only take a Posthuman with Taskmaster-like abilities seconds or minutes to learn skills. This is why a poly-peak human wouldn't be able to learn everything. Because their capacity to learn skills is still in the same realm of possibility as regular humans.

When it comes to regular humans, a regular martial artist would probably struggle to take on a physical peak human by themselves. But a regular martial artist can probably beat a mental peak human, because usually, their skill(s) would *just* be mental, meaning there would be no physicality to worry about.

Now, back to the title question:

**Is it odd to overestimate the danger of peak human characters or characters without powers?**

Are peak humans considered too weak to be taken seriously as threats in a world full of mutants and magic users? That's my question here.

There are some criminal organizations in my world where all the members are peak humans. The members are usually ninjas or samurai. Also, peak humans are the biggest superhuman population in my world, with Posthumans being the second-biggest.

When I look at superhero stories, supernatural stories, or even battle anime stories, the most dangerous serial killers, hitmen, and assassins are usually portrayed as characters without any superpowers. I find that interesting, how these supervillains can still be a threat in a world where powerful mutant and magical beings exist.

So my main question here is: **what should I consider when it comes to the dangers or threats of peak humans existing in a world?**

Comment: I think we humans have done a pretty good job at bringing the world to the brink of disaster in several ways without needing any super powers. You don't need a lot of abilities to be a danger to yourself, others and the world. (NB there is also a stack exchange dedicate to worldbuiling: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/ )

Comment: How peak is your peak and how super is your super? In comic books/MCU, DC world, top (or peak) humans can often stand their ground against superpowered ones, but more importantly, they are able to devise a plan to defeat the ones considered invulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

Much depends on the skill set.  A hero with Superman's skill set -- supersense, superstrength, flight, and invulnerability -- will be dangerously vulnerable to a peak human who's mastered disguise skills and goes for surreptitious crimes, such that unless he is seen in the right moment, it's all but impossible to prove he did something.

Furthermore, superheroes care about normal humans.  Peak humans pose a grave danger to *them*.